# Unable to get value of the property '0': object is null or undefined in IE7

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using highcharts for pie charts. There is a problem in the script in IE7 which says:

`SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property '0': object is null or undefined 
highcharts.js, line 10 character 3841`

Here is the line of code from the script:

```
if(typeof a[0]==="number")
    this.x=a[0],this.y=a[1];
else if(d==="object"&&typeof a.length!=="number") {
    if(u(this,a),this.options=a,a.dataLabels)c._hasPointLabels=!0
}
else if(typeof a[0]==="string")
    this.name=a[0],this.y=a[1];
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Could you post the options that you are passing to Highcharts?

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me as well. After debugging, I eventually found the issue was because I had an extra comma ',' after the last element of my series data array.

An example of the issue can be found on this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lewisdavidcole/Be43c/14/

The error only showed up in IE7 and IE8. It worked fine in IE9, Chrome and Firefox, which are more forgiving. To fix the issue, remove the extra comma on line 266 of the JSFIddle that looks like this:

`}, //TO FIX, REMOVE THE EXTRA COMMA HERE WHICH CREATES PROBLEMS IN IE7 and IE8`

The error happened because defining an array like
`var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5,];`
Creates an issue in IE7 and IE8, it should never end in a comma.

Comment: Extra comma at end was causing problem! you saved my day.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common misconfiguration, so we added a fix for it in Highcharts. See http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/sw5rY/ .

```
series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2,],
    showInLegend: true
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please alert(a[0]) and see does that array element has some value or not
If not please used this condition before your code:-

```
if(a.length>0){
//your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if(a.length>0){
if(typeof a[0]==="number")
    this.x=a[0],this.y=a[1];
else if(d==="object"&&typeof a.length!=="number") {
    if(u(this,a),this.options=a,a.dataLabels)c._hasPointLabels=!0
}
else if(typeof a[0]==="string")
    this.name=a[0],this.y=a[1];
}
```